# How do you specify a parent category using the Discord API?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to create a ticket discord bot that generates a text channel and places it in a category. Here is what I have currently:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Category;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.TextChannelImpl;

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals(".new")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Created new Ticket");
            event.getGuild().createTextChannel("Ticket", "777209975935467541");
             
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps giving telling me the category ("777209975935467541") can not be a String or Long. If anyone can help me that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `category.createTextChannel("ticket").queue()`.

Example:

```java
MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel();
Category category = event.getGuild().getCategoryById(777209975935467541L);
if (category == null) {
  channel.sendMessage("Cannot create a ticket, because i didn't use the right channel id for the category!").queue();
  return;
}

category.createTextChannel("ticket")
        .flatMap(ticket -> channel.sendMessageFormat("Created ticket at %s", ticket))
        .queue();
```

See [Category#createTextChannel](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Category.html#createTextChannel(java.lang.String)).

Comment: That fixed the problem!